# SQL Database Design - 'Stamping' fields/duplicating records

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I've come across a couple of situations where 'stamping' fields (/duplicating them) looks like it's going to make processes a lot simpler, and in both cases it's where there is a distinction between a record 'being used' by something as opposed to 'belonging' to something.

That probably doesn't make a lot of sense so here are some examples:

**Example 1:  Address**

An Address might 'belong to' a:

- User
- Venue
- Supplier

and it might be 'used by' a:

- Order
- Booking

If, rather than allowing an Order/Booking to reference an existing Address, I always duplicate the Address (either within the Address table or elsewhere), so that the Order/Booking is effectively an 'owner' as well (meaning *any* Address has precisely one owner), the system logic is very simple:  the owner of an Address can update/delete as they please.  Unfortunately, it also means a lot more storage space used for usually no good reason (ultimately).

Otherwise, a system of 'soft deletes' and 'row locks' and creating new rows every time there's a change to a locked row becomes necessary.

**Example 2:  Service**

(Similar to the first example)

A Service (service_type, duration, max_clients, cancellation_notice_required, price) 'belongs to' a:

- User

and might be 'used by' a:

- Booking

So if I don't 'stamp' the service details on a Booking, and the Booking gets changed, I have to an add an entry to the Service table every time there is a change to any of the fields corresponding to a service (or otherwise have some logic that figures out when to update).

**Question**

Is 'stamping' fields/duplicating records a good idea?  Is there a better solution to this type of problem?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are storing the current value of something (address or service) when something happens (say a booking).

That is very reasonable, and definitely one viable way of handling slowly changing dimensions.  It does come at a cost of potentially storing lots of unnecessary information in each booking.  Another alternative is to use effective and end dates on addresses/services so all the versions are in one place.

Whether it is a good idea in your case, depends on other factors you don't touch on, such as the cardinality of the tables, the frequency of changes, the types of queries, and the width of the records.

I should note something else.  Addresses for vendors, venues, and suppliers might sort-of look the same, but they might be different.  For instance, suppliers might have billing addresses and delivery addresses, each with special instructions.  Venues might have spaces that can be combined.